# detecting collision between two images in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this game :http://jsfiddle.net/Qfe6L/5/

i am trying to detect when a shuriken hit an enemy so when it hit it the enemy should disappear and the score  should be increased by 1 what i searched for is that i should calculate the position of the two images to check whether their is a collision but i don't seem i can do that any help from you guys ?

```
 $(window).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 32) {
                CreateChuriken();
                $("#Shuriken" + Shurikengid).animate({ left: '+=300px' }, 'slow');

                if ($(".Shuriken").css('left') == $(".Enemy").css('left'))
                { alert("Met"); }
            }
        });
```

Comment: first make the focus on the container div and try it using firefox please

Comment: To check the key crossbrowser you could do something like `var key = e.keyCode | e.which;` and check the `key`. But anyway, I think you have to check all sides, so not only `css('left')` but also `width` and `height`. Search SO for 'collision detection jQuery'.

Comment: Im afraid it will not work in this way. :( It will be difficult to catch moment when `.Shuriken` cross `.Enemy`. You have to do it on lower abstraction level without `animate` function.

Comment: what do you mean by lower abstraction level

Comment: As i noticed, dont use `animate` function. You need turns. In every turn you have to move elements, create shurinens (and enemies), check collisions etc.

Comment: can u provide an example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for collision in each animation step. Fortunately jQuery `.animate()` has a `progress` option, which you can pass a function to be called every frame.

```
$("#Shuriken" + Shurikengid).animate(
    { left: '+=300px' }, 
    { duration : 'slow', 
      progress: function(){
                    /* collision detection here */
                }
    }
);
```

Keep in mind that

```
if ($(".Shuriken").css('left') == $(".Enemy").css('left'))
```

will only compare position of first projectile and first enemy, while there are more of them on the screen. You need to iterate over every projectile and compare its powition with every enemy to find a colliding pair, like:

```
$('.Shuriken').each( function(){
    var sOffset = $(this).offset();
    $('.Enemy').each( function(){
        var eOffset = $(this).offset();
        if( sOffset.left == eOffset.left ){
            /* boom! */
        }
    });
});
```

The above is close, but still won't work. Animation doesn't progress by 1px each frame, so you may go from Shuriken at 100px left and Enemy at 101px left at one frame to Shuriken at 102px left and Enemy at 99px left in the next one. They'll pass each other, but won't meet at the same point. So you'd need to round these values to, say, nearest 10s which will give you a bigger tolerance. You sholud also compare the vertical positions.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qfe6L/8/
(Fixed vertical posiotion of Enemies for easier testing).

Edit:
as suggested by @Kasyx it would be better to move all of this out of animation function and create a Game Loop and Scene Graph. Scene graph would keep track of elements' positions, and within Game Loop you'd check for collisions, then call a rendering function which would draw elements on screen based on the scene graph.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you’re running your hit check function once, directly after you’ve started the animation. What you need to be doing is running it every frame to see the intersect. Luckily jQuery provides a callback handler for this: [$.animate’s step option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step). If you pass a second object into `$.animate` you can specify both your duration and step function like so:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    CreateChuriken();
    $("#Shuriken" + Shurikengid).animate({
      left: '+=300px'
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      step: function(){
        if ($(".Shuriken").css('left') == $(".Enemy").css('left')) {
          alert("Met");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

As you’re calling your step function once every frame you’ll want to cache your selectors inside (`$('.Shuriken')`, `$('.Enemy')`) first:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 32) {
    var shuriken, enemy;
    CreateChuriken();
    shuriken = $('.Shuriken');
    enemy = $('.Enemy');
    $("#Shuriken" + Shurikengid).animate({
      left: '+=300px'
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      step: function(){
        if (shuriken.css('left') == enemy.css('left')) {
          alert("Met");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You could skip the `shuriken.css('left')`, it's passed to `step` callback function as the first argument. But you need to compare shuriken's position with every enemy in the collection, not just the first one. 
`step: function( left ){ enemy.each( function(){ if( this.style.left == left){ alert("met!") }});`